# MSSQL 2005 Query to insert value as bonus on the current value?

Tags: sql-server-2005, insert

I've got a table with column `Points` in it. Players at the moment have points but I want to add to all players `+100 Points` to their current ones. How the SQL query will look like ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update pointsTable set Points = Points + 100
```